# Modifying font glyphs in Eclipse editor API?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my Eclipse plugin I'd like to be able to modify characters in the Editor a bit. Is it possible to somehow access pixel data for each character glyph, or/and maybe even the pixel data for each character in an Editor?

PS: maybe it is also possible to access Editor pixel data?

Comment: SWT doesn't really know anything about how fonts are rendered - that is left up to the native code. So I think you would really struggle to do this. If you explain what you are trying to achieve there might be an easier way.

Comment: @greg-449 But somehow it can change color to highlight them. I just need to change color and add some mark near the character that is not available as a font file. I would really like to avoid changing any font files and prefer to modify the pixel data a little since there can be many marks.

Comment: Color does not require modifying the font, it is just a parameter when drawing the text. The editor has plenty of support for color and various overlays and highlighting without having to modify anything.

Comment: @greg-449 I need to draw color-coded marks upon some of the characters, but being aware of what pixels are taken by a character. Maybe there is another way to acheive that, like with some overlay.. but still - how I know which pixels has what color..